# How to write a AutoIT script that pastes a paragraph using a hotkey

Tags: jira, autoit

I need some help on how to write a AutoIt script that can be used to paste a particular paragraph whenever I press a certain hotkey within JIRA. Can anyone help me out?

This is what I have thus far:

```
Func DoNotReply()
   ClipPut("Please do not reply to this email")
EndFunc

HotKeySet("!{q}", "DoNotReply")

While 1
  Sleep(10)
WEnd
```

-Thanks!

Comment: `HotKeySet("!q", "DoNotReply")`. The `{}` syntax is reserved for "special keys" like `{ESC}`, `{PAUSE}` etc. Simple letters don't need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper `HotKeySet` syntax for "normal" keys (letters) doesn't use `{}`. Also, you might want to directly send the string instead of overwriting the clipboard (which might contain something you like to keep there). Use the `Send` command:

```
HotKeySet("!q", "DoNotReply")

While 1
  Sleep(10)
WEnd  

Func DoNotReply()
   Send("Please do not reply to this email")
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

I think this will work:

```
Func ClosedTicketReply()
    ClipPut("PLEASE DO NOT REPLY to this email.")
    Send("^v")
EndFunc

HotKeySet("!{q}","ClosedTicketReply")

While 1
    Sleep(10)
WEnd
```

I haven't figured out how to format though. So any tips on that would be greatly appreciated.